# Can I use fio on a mounted device?

Tags: storage, benchmark

I'm using fio to get some broad read IOPS performance data for various storage configurations like this:

```
fio --name=readiops --filename=/dev/md1 --direct=1 --rw=randread --bs=4k --numjobs=4 --iodepth=32 --direct=1 --iodepth_batch=16 --iodepth_batch_complete=16 \
    --runtime=100 --ramp_time=5 --norandommap --time_based --ioengine=libaio --group_reporting
readiops: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=4K-4K/4K-4K/4K-4K, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
...
fio-2.1.11
Starting 4 processes
Jobs: 4 (f=4): [r(4)] [100.0% done] [3504MB/0KB/0KB /s] [897K/0/0 iops] [eta 00m:00s]
readiops: (groupid=0, jobs=4): err= 0: pid=10458: Thu Jan 15 05:49:28 2015
...
```

I'd like to compare the figures I'm getting with an array that is in production use at a quiet time, is this possible to do without affecting the data on the array?

There is a `--readonly` option (duplicated for some reason) [in the `man` page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fio) but it isn't 100% clear to me that this is what I'm after:

> --readonly
>       Enable read-only safety checks.
>   ...
>   --readonly
>       Turn on safety read-only checks, preventing any attempted write.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another way, but we ended up deciding to create a loopback device to a big file on the mounted array, then run the test on that:

```
fio --name=readiops --filename=/dev/loop0 --direct=1 --rw=randread --bs=4k --numjobs=4 --iodepth=32 --direct=1 --iodepth_batch=16 --iodepth_batch_complete=16 \
    --runtime=100 --ramp_time=5 --norandommap --time_based --ioengine=libaio --group_reporting
```

Comment: Are you SURE it's worth the risks to bench on a production system (what if you trigger a kernel error)? Philosophical questions aside, using a file within the filesystem will add filesystem overhead but one slip in your fio command line is far less likely to damage lots of different file data in one brief go. Using a loopback device atop the file will make things a bit slower again - you could just use the file directly as part of filename directly (assuming your filesystem supports files being opened O_DIRECT) - just ensure the file already exists before running fio.